# how can I iterate over SOME of the TH elements in <thead><tr>

Tags: javascript, loops, html-table, columnheader

Let's say there are 6 `th` elements

```
    <thead>
      <tr><th></th><th></th><th></th> <th></th><th></th><th></th></tr>
    </thead>
```

and I want to iterate over the first 4 only. How do I get an iterable list of these elements so I can do something like this:

```
    while (i < myLimit) {
          th = thlist[i];
          // do something : if somecondition myLimit +=1;
          i++;
    }
    return i;
```

The `th` elements are decorated, *some of them*, with style="display:none" and I'm trying to figure out how many such decorated `th` elements there are to the left of an arbitrarily chosen one.

NOTE: myLimit may have to be increased during the iteration!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getElementByTagName javascript pure function, like this:

```
function getStyle(elem, cssprop, cssprop2){
 // IE
 if (elem.currentStyle) {
   return elem.currentStyle[cssprop];

 // other browsers
 } else if (document.defaultView &&
                   document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
   return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem,
null).getPropertyValue(cssprop2);

 // fallback
 } else {
   return null;
 }
}


var ths = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
var myLimit = 4;

var max = ths.length;

if (myLimit>max)
    myLimit = max;

for (var i = 0;i < myLimit; i++) {
    // do something with myarray[i]
    var th = ths[i];
    if (getStyle(th,'display','display')=='none')
        alert('th in position '+i+' is decorated with display:none');
}
```

here is a live example working http://jsfiddle.net/aJ8MS/

Comment: This iterates over all 6 elements

Comment: @sandino: thanks for the DOM functions and code to get the style. Very helpful.

Comment: Couldn't you simplify getting the style a bit by using `element.getAttribute('display')` (it's pure JS)? I know with the function you get the style also if it's set through CSS, but it seems to me that getAttribute would suffice here.

Answer (score 0):

You can gather the first 4 (or n) elements like this:

```
var limit = 4,
    $ths = $('th:not(:nth-child('+limit+') ~ th)', 'thead');
```

then iterate for example with .each():

```
$ths.each(function() {
  console.log(this);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z77nQ/6/)

or another approach:

```
var limit = 4,
    $ths = $('th', 'thead');

$ths.each( function() {
    var id = $(this).index();
    if(id < limit) {
        console.log(this);
        // increase limit on certain condition
        if(id == 2) limit++;
    }
});

return limit;
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z77nQ/7/)

To check if an element has `display: none` simply:

```
$this.is(':hidden')
```

Comment: Good answer but the question initially asked for a non jquery solution a javascript pure one

Comment: Where does he ask for a non-jquery solution? Also, the question is tagged with jquery.

Comment: he edit the answer, maybe he cut off that paragraph, sorry :O

Comment: Well especially with the jquery tag that's a bit confusing ;D

Comment: You are rigth it is a bit confusing, he asked for a purely javascript solution and accepted my solution that starts like: 'You can use getElementByTagName javascript pure function, like this:' so I edited the tag 'jquery' to 'javascript' thanks for your help Simon

Comment: You guys are just so dang fast. :-)  I took maybe a few breaths before removing the non-jQuery part of the question.

Comment: @Simon: is.(':hidden') equates to style.display.none?  I'm not against jQuery, but I needed the iterator function to return a value, which each() doesn't, right?

Comment: _Elements can be considered hidden for several reasons: They have a CSS display value of none. They are form elements with type="hidden". Their width and height are explicitly set to 0. An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page._ From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

Comment: Updated answer for the `return value` part, just for the records.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to access rows and cells in a table is to use the built in properties. Usually the headers are found in the first row (it is the case in your question), so the ths are the cells contained in table.rows[0]:

```
var table=document.getElementById("myTable"),
    i=0,
    count=0,
    myLimit=4;
while (i < myLimit) {
    if (table.rows[0].cells[i].style.display=="none") { count ++; }
    i++;
}
return count;
```

Answer (score 0):

I started with sandino's solution and used Christophe's check for the display none style.

The tricksy thing about this situation is that I'm using a kendo grid, which splits the grid into two tables, one for the header and another for the body rows. The two tables can have a different number of columns if some columns are hidden because the body-grid contains only the visible columns whereas the header-grid has definitions even for the invisible columns.

Let's say there are 12 columns in the grid and the first 7 are hidden. The header-grid contains all 12, with the first 7 decorated with display:none.  The content-grid contains only the 5 visible columns.  So when the user clicks on the first visible column, index 0, that actually corresponds to the 8th column in the header grid (0-based, so index = 7).

To find the column-header that corresponds to the VisibleIndex 0, we have to add to the index of the clicked cell the number of hidden columns that are to the left of it. We add 7 to 0 to get 7.

```
 function countHiddenColumnHeadersLeft(id, clickedCellIndex) {    
    var ths = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByClassName('k-header');
    var myLimit = clickedCellIndex;   


    var invisicount = 0;

    for (var i = 0; (i < myLimit) ; i++) {        
      var th = ths[i];
      if (th.style.display == 'none') {
            invisicount++;
            myLimit++;
        }        
    }
    return invisicount;
}
```